# The network connection is lost in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting an error time to time while making requests,

```
Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <BB6171AF-E4AF-49F2-ACEE-A2CDA67B825E>.<3>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
  "LocalDataTask <BB6171AF-E4AF-49F2-ACEE-A2CDA67B825E>.<3>",
  "LocalDataPDTask <BB6171AF-E4AF-49F2-ACEE-A2CDA67B825E>.<3>",
  "LocalDataTask <BB6171AF-E4AF-49F2-ACEE-A2CDA67B825E>.<3>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://url, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://url})
```

Why am I getting this error?

I have a method which handles api calls called retry() and depending on the status i need to refresh my token and then retry the same request again. So what I have done is check whether the response after excuting the initial api call is SOMECODE and then refresh the access token if it is calling the refreshAccessToken method and depending on its response if it's a success then I recursively call the same function retry() again and excute the logic. It works fine sometimes and sometimes it gives the above error. The code which performs the above operation is posted below,

```
if responseDescDisplay == "SOMECODE"{
     refreshAccessToken(){ isSuccess,isFailed, errCode in
      if isSuccess {
       retry(urlString: urlString, method: method, requestBody: requestBody, completionHandler: completionHandler)
       performRetry = true;
      }else{
       if !performRetry {
        if errCode.isEmpty {
         completionHandler(nil,nil,"OHNO");
        }else{
         completionHandler(nil,nil,"ERROR");
        }
         
       }
      }
```

My access token refreshing method looks something like this,

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: tokenRegenerateRequest) { data, res, err in
  print("EROR: ", err)
  print("DARA: ", data)
  if err != nil {
   print("IN HERE")
   completionHandler(false, false, "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR");
  }
  guard let data = data, err == nil else {return}
  guard let httpResponse = res as? HTTPURLResponse else {
   return
  }
   
   
  //    print("REGENRATING TOKEN \(httpResponse.statusCode) \(res)");
  if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
   if !data.isEmpty {
    do {
     let decodedResponse = try! JSONDecoder().decode(RefreshTokenResponse.self, from: data);
     print("ACCESS TOKEN REGENRATE REQUEST: ", decodedResponse)
     if !decodedResponse.accessToken.isEmpty && !decodedResponse.refreshToken.isEmpty {
       
      completionHandler(true,false, "")
     } else {
      print("HERE1")
      completionHandler(false,true,"")
     }
    }catch{
     print("HERE2")
     completionHandler(false,true,"")
    }
   } else {
    print("HERE3")
    completionHandler(false,true,"")
   }
  }else {
   print("HERE4", httpResponse.statusCode)
   completionHandler(false,true,"")
  }
   
 }.resume()
```

What am i doing wrong. Why do I keep getting the above error? Please can anyone post/suggest a possible way to overcome this issue? Please don't suggest to use any other libraries since I am stick to URLSession. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you track your url string value ? the error ends with : http://url .

Comment: What do you do in completionHandler ?

Comment: Is there a limit on the server side to the number of requests within a certain time?

Comment: @PtitXav I didn't understand the first question? Yeah I use the completion handler in the access token refreshing method to notifiy the initial method it's calling which is the code I have posted first. And the completion handler in that method is used to notify the UI

Comment: @koen Nope there isn't any. I have implemented the same logic in react native and it works fine without any issue

Comment: The first comment refers to “NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://url” in the error. So, did you check if “urlString” is correct for every request?

Comment: Yeah @koen the urls are correct

Comment: What print do you get when you have error ? Why not doing return when err is not nil ? You also set performRetry after the call to retry.

Comment: Yeah I get the above error in the first comment and the error is not nil. It executes the log statement "IN HERE".